# When can we ignore small-oh inside of a limit and when we cannot?

Tags: calculus, limits

Here's an example.
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\ln\left(1 + x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1\right) - x}{x^3}.$$
$\ln(1 + x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1) \sim  x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1$ (the limit of their division is equal to 1). And so the left side we can replace with $x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1 + o(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1)$. Now if we write it inside of the limit we'll have
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac {x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1 + o\left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1\right) - x}{x^3}
$$
Here we can cancel the two x-es. Now what I'm wondering about is why can't I ignore the small-oh in this limit? In fact the limit of the expression is not the same with and without the small-oh (with small-oh I mean the $o(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1)$).
And more generally where can we ignore and when we cannot?
For example
If we have
$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac {\ln(1+x)} {x}$ here
$\ln(1+x) = x + o(x)$ and so if we ignore $o(x)$ then we'll have this limit $\lim_{x \to 0} x/x = 1$ which's correct. So what's the difference and how can I detect it in problems to avoid errors?

Comment: You've an error in your way of calculating:  you should expand all quantities by powers of $x$. This means you have to expand $\sqrt{1+x^2} first. Also, all quantities have to be expanded at the same order.

Comment: I have doubts about $\ln(1 + x + \sqrt{1 + x^2} - 1) \sim  x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}$ because of $-1$

Comment: @Bernard yes, thanks. It's just I had done in that way later and the result was the same. I mean first I expanded the square root and then ln and the result was the same as if I expand first the ln and then the square root

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may sound a bit redundant, but you can ignore the small-oh when the order of convergence of $o$ is smaller than that of the denominator, what I'm saying is, if you have $f(x)=g(x)+o(x)$ where $\lim_{x\to a}o(x)=0$ then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ if $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{o(x)}{h(x)}=0$, the better $g$ aproximates $f$ then the statement $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ will be true for more $h$, but there is no universal rule because the only perfect aproximation of $f$ is $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the example. The denominator is $x^3$. So it is enough to know both numerator and denominator modulo $o(x^3)$. Well, since i prefer the big-oh-notation, let us please work modulo $O(x^4)$, it is possible here.

In the numerator, the term $-x$ is clear, so we need to know $\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})+O(x^4)$. I.e. the Taylor polynomial of $\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$ in $0$ with the corresponding "precision". Note that "building Taylor polynomials" is an operation compatible with composition in a certain sense. In our case, we have the compositions $U_0\to V_1\overset\ln\to W_0$, where $U_0$ is some ("good small")
neighbourhood of $0$, $V_1$ of $1$, and $W_0$ of $0$. The function from $U_0\to V_1$ is $x\to x+\sqrt{1+x^2}$. Now we can get even more involved in the bureaucracy of Taylor polynomials, and separate the $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ part, since it involves $x^2$. I will write $h$ for $x^2$. And i will go with $h$ till $O(h^4)$ to see that later we only need $O(h^2)$, which may by an answer by example for the OP.)

Now one can formally write:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{1+h}
&= (1+h)^{1/2} = \binom{1/2}0 + \binom{1/2}1 h+ \binom{1/2}2 h^2 + \binom{1/2}3 h^3 + O(h^4)\\
&=1 +\frac 12h-\frac 18h^2+\frac 1{16}h^3+O(h^4)
\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{(Do we really/minimally need $O(h^4)$ for the later $O(x^4)$-"precision"?!)}\\
\sqrt{1+x^2} 
&=1 +\frac 12x^2-\frac 18x^4+\frac 1{16}x^6+O(x^8)\\
&=1 +\frac 12x^2+O(x^4)\ .\\
&\qquad\text{(No, $O(h^2)$ would have been enough above for the $O(x^4)$-"precision"...)}\\
x +\sqrt{1+x^2} 
&=1 +x+\frac 12x^2+O(x^4)\ .\\
\ln(x +\sqrt{1+x^2})
&=\ln\Bigg(1 +\underbrace{\left(x+\frac 12x^2\right)}_{=:w\text{ and }O(x)=O(w)}\Bigg)+O(x^4)
\\
&=w-\frac 12w^2+\frac 13w^3+O(w^4)
\\
&=\left(x+\frac 12x^2\right)
-\frac 12\left(x+\frac 12x^2\right)^2
+\frac 13\left(x+\frac 12x^2\right)^3+O(x^4)
\\
&=\left(x+\frac 12x^2\right)
-\frac 12\left(x^2+2\cdot\frac 12x^3+O(x^4)\right)
+\frac 13\left(x^3+O(x^4)\right)+O(x^4)
\\
&=x-\frac 16x^3+O(x^4)\ .
\\
\ln(x +\sqrt{1+x^2})- x 
&= 
-\frac 16x^3+O(x^4)
\\
\frac{\ln(x +\sqrt{1+x^2})- x}{x^3}
&= 
-\frac 16+O(x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the answer may be for short the following one. When the involved "pieces" (w.r.t. the operations addition, subtraction, multiplication, composition, division) are analytic functions with known Taylor expansions, one has to follow the degree needed for each piece. Sometimes compositions and multiplicaiont may make the "needed precision" become smaller. In the above example, the "degree-two-map" $x\to h=x^2$ is such an expample, when the precision "in $h$" is not $O(h^4)$, but the smaller $O(h^2)$.

(So even shorter, compute the valuation in the corresponding ring of formal power series modulo the needed precision.)

Comment: However, you can't in general replace $+o(x^n)$ with $+O(x^{n+1})$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, sure, i only wanted to work modulo $O(h^2)$ which clearly corresponds to $O(x^4)$, and lets me write $1+\frac 12x^2+ O(x^4)$, which feels (phychologically) much better than $1+\frac 12x^2+ o(x^2)$. Then if we try to do the last steps using $o$ instead of $O$, and weight the differences, there is a didactical plus when using $O$. For instance, we have $(x+\frac12x^3)^2=x^2+\frac 12x^3+o(x^3)$, and $(x+\frac12x^3)^3=x^3+o(x^3)$, but we have even more $(x+\frac12x^3)^2=x^2+\frac 12x^3+O(x^4)$, and $(x+\frac12x^3)^3=x^3+O(x^4)$, and $O(x^4)$ is easier to read "+terms of degree $\ge 4$".

Comment: Also, a lot of $=$ should be $\in$ or $\subseteq$, [but never mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation).